# Stokes Theorem, Evaluating the Integral with z<1 over a cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

First I find the intersection that is $z=1$ and parametrize it:

$r(t)=1cost(i)+1sint(j)+1(k)$

$r'(t)=-sint(i)+cost(j)$

I then substitute this into $\int_C \! F(r(t)\cdot r'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$ to get:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \! sin^2(t)(cost-cos^2t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$

I don't think this is correct because the $z=<0$ and I don't know what to do with oriebtation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I don't think this is correct because the z=<0" ?

Comment: As for the orientation, it simply tells you which direction to integrate around the boundary of the surface. In this case, since the surface is oriented in the positive z-direction, you integrate counterclockwise about the circle, assuming you were looking down on the surface from a higher position on the z-axis. As such, your line integral looks correct to me. I got the same line integral when I did the problem myself.

Comment: I'm just wondering what does the Stokes Thm calculate. I thought we find the integral of the Surface which to me should be infinite if you imagine a cylinder that goes all the way to -infinity on the z plane.

Comment: Sorry, why are you imagining a cylinder? Also, I'm unclear on what you mean by the z-plane. There is no unique z-plane. Planes are defined by two lines. For example, the xy-plane is the unique plane passing through the x-axis and the y-axis.

Comment: I meant the z direction, but I get that it's not a cylinder now, it's a cone. And z can't be negative because y^2+x^2>0 for all x,y. So does it mean that the surface area of that cone is Pi/4? And the negative answer is simply the orientation chosen

Comment: The surface may look like a cone, but it's actually a paraboloid. The distinction is important; it completely changes the surface over which you're integrating. The result of the integral does not mean that the surface area of the paraboloid is $\pi$/4. In fact, the surface integral you're evaluating gives the flux of the curl of $\vec{F}$ over the surface of the paraboloid. It depends on the surface area of the paraboloid, but does not yield the surface area as an answer.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense when you mention flux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line integral over $C =\{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = 1\} $is

$$L =\oint_Cx^2y\, dx+ \oint_Cy^2z \, dy+ \oint_Cz^2x\, dz.$$

On $C$ we have $z = 1, dz = 0.$

Hence, with counterclockwise orientation

$$L =\oint_Cx^2y\, dx+ \oint_Cy^2 \, dy \\ =-\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 t \sin^2 t\, dt+ \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2 t \cos t\, dt\\=-\frac1{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(2t) \, dt +\frac1{3}\sin^3 t|_0^{2\pi}\\=-\frac1{8}\int_0^{2\pi}(1 -\cos(4t)) \, dt \\=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$